# Producing clickable hyperlinks in ipe

Tags: hyperref, urls, presentations, ipe

I'm starting to use [**ipe**](http://ipe7.sourceforge.net/) to create slides for a presentation. But LaTeX does not behave the way I am used to. For example, I want to use the `hyperref` package to have URLs with a different font which are also clickable in the pdf. Therefore I import `hyperref` in the preamble of my ipe document:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathaccent"017E {#1}}

% settings %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\itemcolor}{KITgreen}
\newcommand{\name}{Author}
\newcommand{\prestitle}{Title}

% my packages
\usepackage{hyperref}

% my commands
```

Then I try to use the `\href` or `\url` command inside an ipe text box:

```
\textcolor{KITblue}{
Authors: \textit{Title} - arXiv.org preprint, April 2013 \href{http://arxiv.org/abs/555.555}{arxiv.org/abs/555.555}
}
```

Now LaTeX compilation fails with:

```
{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
! pdfTeX error (ext4): link annotations cannot be inside an XForm.
\@EveryShipout@Output ...@Org@Shipout \box \@cclv 

l.356 \end{document}
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: How about adding a compilable MWE starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` so one can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @karlkoeller This is LaTeX inside ipe, not a .tex document. Can you tell me how to make a reproducible example without posting all the files?

Comment: The documentation of ipe says on page 9 "You cannot use commands that involve a non-linear translation into PDF, such
as commands to generate hyperlinks or to include external images.". It also says (p. 24) that the complete tex-file ipetemp.tex can be found in a temporary folder.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You may expand this comment to an answer, i.e. clstaudt can achieve his/her goal by editing the generated ipetemp.tex file, as you indicate in your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of ipe says on page 9 "You cannot use commands that involve a non-linear translation into PDF, such as commands to generate hyperlinks or to include external images.". It also says (p. 24) that the complete tex-file `ipetemp.tex` can be found in a temporary folder.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative way is the following:

1. create a textbox with your link text
2. Make it a group containing itself
3. Use set link action to set the destination link

See http://ipe.otfried.org/manual/onepage.html#id31 for more details.